# How do people place code blocks in comments?

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

Currently when I want to place a small piece of code in my comment... I click on help link and copy and paste the code single quotes, does anyone have a better method?

```
`
```

But when you write a question or answer, there is an easy `Command + K` short cut, why doesn't this same short cut work while writing a comment?

I understand the argument that code isn't supposed to be in comments... but why would they allow comments to accept a code block? Why not just disable all code in comments?

If comments accept code, then they should use the same `Command + K` short cut to access it.

Comment: These are not single quotes, these are backticks. Depending on your keyboard layouts they can be situated at various places. On the US keyboard layout they are on the top left key just under ESC.

Comment: Oh, my bad... I didn't even notice that it was the key to the left one my `1` key... but I still think they should allow the `command + K` shortcut

Comment: @HugoDozois This is going to make my life so much easier! Perhaps an answer?

Comment: @RichardTingle: [Not sure if serious](http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5044/5269558397_64406aeb94_z.jpg).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Alas I am, perhaps I should be more embarrassed by my lack of knowledge regarding my own keyboard. But I’m not damn it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are not single quotes, these are [backticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick). Depending on your keyboard layouts they can be situated at various places. On the US keyboard layout they are on the top left key just under ESC.

[image: keyboardLayout]

Comment: YAY! A hand drawn circle! I really don't think many people know that the code mark is actually a backtick, and a key on the keyboard, thanks!

Comment: You mean all this is about is the backticks?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, previously I would click the 'help' link under 'add comment', and it would show an example how to use code... I would then copy the backtick and use it that way.

Comment: [And other keyboard layouts are covered in this SuperUser answer](http://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows/254077#254077)

Answer (score 8):

> does anyone have a better method?

Nope.  That's the way to do it.

> But when you write a question or answer, there is an easy Command + K short cut, why doesn't this same short cut work while writing a comment?

Because comments are second-class citizens.  They don't support inline carriage returns, and so are not suitable for extended code blocks.  They are intended for clarification, not for posting code.

> why would they allow comments to accept a code block? Why not just disable all code in comments?

Because it can be useful to have the ability to point out errors in someone else' code.

Comment: This is why new coders aren't coming here. Programming to the interface, not to the implementation.

_"They don't support inline carriage returns, and so are not suitable for extended code blocks. They are intended for clarification, not for posting code."_